# What is the difference between Obj obj =new Obj (); and Obj obj;

Tags: java, class, object, instantiation

What is the difference between `Obj obj =new Obj ();` and `Obj obj;` (without instantiation)

in java

```java
public class Obj {

    int a =1;

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Obj obj =new Obj ();
        Obj obj1;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: You already answered it yourself. The first one initialises the variable, the first one only declares.

Comment: One instantiates an object, the other only declares.

Answer (score -1):

`Obj obj = new Obj();` - Here the object is created and the reference of `Obj` is created which is `obj`. Since we have used `new Obj()`, memory will be allocated in this case.

`Obj obj1;` - Here reference of Obj is been created which is `obj1`. In this case memory will not be allocated.

Hope this helps

Comment: You can use only obj obj =new Obj because the reference is pointing to the actual object . Second case: obj obj1 is just having a reference and not pointing to anything.  Conclusion: You can use only the first case.